# How do I assign the same Javascript code to multiple divs without running it at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, e-commerce

I have a small ecommerce shop made and each of the products has a small product card made with HTML, CSS, and a small bit of Jquery for animations. The problem is that when I click the "add to cart" div, every item gets added to the cart and the animation runs for all of them. I believe the problem might be because the classes/ids for the product cards are the same for every card and the jquery only knows to run that class so it runs all of them, but is there any way to make it so the jquery only runs the animation once per product card? The code is attached:

HTML:

```
    <div class="itemwrapper">
                        <div class="productcontainer">
                            <div class="cardtop" style="
  background: url(images/collar-1.jpeg) no-repeat center center; background-size: contain;"></div>
                            <div class="cardbottom">
                                <div class="cardleft">
                                    <div class="carddetails">
                                        <h1>Multifunction Collar</h1>
                                        <p>$21.99</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cardbuy"><img class="addtocart" src="images/cart-icon.png" width="85px" height="85px" /></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cardright">
                                    <div class="carddone"><img src="images/done.png" width="85px" height="85px" /></div>
                                    <div class="details">
                                        <h1>Multifunction Collar</h1>
                                        <p>Added to your cart</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cardremove"><img src="images/remove-icon.png" width="85px" height="85px" /></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cardinside">
                            <div class="cardicon"><img src="images/info.png" width="30px" height="30px" /> </div>
                            <div class="cardcontents">
                                <table class="cardtable">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Details: </th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px">Multifunction collar with different hooks for tags and leash <br />This collar comes with fine high quality soft interior padding which is made exclusively from goat leather.</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Quantity: </th>
                                        <th></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" max="5" value="1"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JS:

```
    $('.cardbuy').click(function(){
      $('.cardbottom').addClass("clicked");
    });

    $('.cardremove').click(function(){
      $('.cardbottom').removeClass("clicked");
    });
```

CSS:

```
.itemwrapper {
    all: revert;
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    background: white;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0;
    transform: scale(0.95);
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.itemwrapper:hover {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 5px 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardtop {
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom {
    width: 200%;
    height: 20%;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom.clicked {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardleft {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardleft .carddetails {
    padding: 15px;
    float: left;
    width: calc(70% - 40px);
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardleft .cardbuy {
    float: right;
    width: calc(30% - 3px);
    height: 100%;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    transition: background 0.5s;
    border-left: solid thin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardleft .cardbuy i {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 30px;
    color: #254053;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardleft .cardbuy:hover {
    background: #A6CDDE;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardleft .cardbuy:hover i {
    transform: translateY(5px);
    color: #00394B;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardright {
    width: 50%;
    background: #A6CDDE;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    height: 200%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardright .details {
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
    width: calc(70% - 40px);
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardright .carddone {
    width: calc(30% - 2px);
    float: left;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    border-right: solid thin rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    height: 50%;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardright .carddone i {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 30px;
    color: white;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardright .cardremove {
    width: calc(30% - 1px);
    clear: both;
    border-right: solid thin rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    height: 50%;
    background: #BC3B59;
    transition: transform 0.5s, background 0.5s;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardright .cardremove:hover {
    background: #9B2847;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardright .cardremove:hover i {
    transform: translateY(5px);
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardright .cardremove i {
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 30px;
    color: white;
}

.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardright:hover .cardremove,
.itemwrapper .productcontainer .cardbottom .cardright:hover .carddone {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.itemwrapper .cardinside {
    z-index: 9;
    background: rgb(255, 232, 209);
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -70px;
    right: -70px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 200px 200px;
    transition: all 0.5s, border-radius 2s, top 1s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.itemwrapper .cardinside .cardicon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 85px;
    top: 85px;
    color: white;
    opacity: 1;
}

.itemwrapper .cardinside:hover {
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 80%;
}

.itemwrapper .cardinside:hover .cardicon {
    opacity: 0;
    right: 15px;
    top: 15px;
}

.itemwrapper .cardinside:hover .cardcontents {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.itemwrapper .cardinside .cardcontents {
    padding: 5%;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transform: translateY(-200%);
    transition: opacity 0.2s, transform 0.8s;
}

.itemwrapper .cardinside .cardcontents .cardtable {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.itemwrapper .cardinside .cardcontents h1,
.itemwrapper .cardinside .cardcontents p,
.itemwrapper .cardinside .cardcontents .cardtable {
    color: black;
}

.itemwrapper .cardinside .cardcontents p {
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to want something like this.

```
$('.cardbuy').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent('.cardbottom').addClass('clicked') // find the closest parent element with the class "cardbottom" and add the "clicked"
})
```

"this" will refer to the element that was clicked. In your code you are targeting *all* elements with the class "cardbuy".

Comment: In my code, the lement that is clicked is an "add to cart" icon, so would "this" refer to the icon? The same icon is used in each product card and each icon has the ".cardbuy" class which is what is causing the problem. Would this still work?

Comment: `$(this)` will refer to the specific element with that class that was clicked in this case. So when you click that product icon, it's looking at that specific `.cardbuy` element, then you are traversing the dom, looking at it's closest `parent` element for a class with with `cardbottom` and adding the class `clicked` to it.